# Simplier way to return custom error type with anyhow::Error?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have working code which returns errors in the following way:

```
fn foo() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    ...
    Err(anyhow::Error::new(
        MyError::MyVariant {
            actual: 0,
            expected: 1
        }
    ))
}
```

Is there a more concise way of returning an instance of `MyError`?

(Omitting the `anyhow::Error::new(` wrapper causes a type-checking error, as `MyError` is not an instance of `anyhow::Error`.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [`anyhow::bail!`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.40/anyhow/macro.bail.html)  macro. It has exactly your usecase in mind:

```rust
use anyhow::bail;

fn foo() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    if errored {
        bail!(MyError::MyVariant { actual: 0, expected: 1 })
    }
}
```

As Filipe correctly points in the comments, if you find yourself checking simple conditions and returning an error you can simplify this step by using [`anyhow::ensure!`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.40/anyhow/macro.ensure.html) which is quite similar to `assert!` but `return`s instead of panicing.

```rust
use anyhow::ensure;

fn foo() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    ensure!(!errored, MyError::MyVariant { actual: 0, expected: 1 });
}
```

Comment: For this specific case of checking a condition and bailing I'd use `anyhow::ensure!(!errored, MyError::MyVariant { actual: 0, expected: 1 })`.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues You're right! I've added it.